# R: Ordering one column conditionally on another and partial order value

Tags: r

I have this dataframe of retweets

```
set.seed(28100)
    df <- data.frame(user_id = sample(1:8, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 timestamp = sample(1:1000, 10),
                 retweet = sample(999:1002, 10, replace=TRUE))
df <- df[with(df, order(retweet, -timestamp)),]
df
# user_id timestamp retweet
# 6        8       513     999
# 9        7       339     999
# 3        3       977    1000
# 2        3       395    1000
# 5        2       333    1000
# 4        5       793    1001
# 1        3       873    1002
# 8        2       638    1002
# 7        4       223    1002
# 10       6        72    1002
```

There is a unique id for each `retweet`. For each row I want to assign a rank to the user according to the inverse order of the chain or retweets. The rank should estimate the *influence* of each user: the longer the chain the highest the point for the early twitterer. In other words I want to rank-order each retweet chain based on the `timestamp` and assign higher points to those who retweeted it before. If two users have posted the same retweet at the same time they should be assign the same ranking.

Or in `df`

```
df$ranking <- c(1,2, 1,2,3, 1, 1,2,3,4)
aggregate(ranking~user_id, data=df, sum)

#   user_id ranking
# 1       2       5
# 2       3       4
# 3       4       3
# 4       5       1
# 5       6       4
# 6       7       2
# 7       8       1
```

Comment: For each `retweet` I use only `timestamp`. The last retweet is assigned `1` then I want to assign increasing values in descending order of `timestamp`. So the first to retweet get the higher value.

Comment: Actually if they have the exact same timestamp they should have the same rank

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry I edited the code

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry about that. Lack of sleep I guess. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using data-table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-timestamp), ranking2 := seq_len(.N), by = retweet]
df[, sum(ranking2), keyby = user_id]
#    user_id V1
# 1:       2  5
# 2:       3  4
# 3:       4  3
# 4:       5  1
# 5:       6  4
# 6:       7  2
# 7:       8  1
```

Comment: There's a problem: for `retweet` 1000 all users are assigned the same rank but they didn't posted the tweet at the same time. Ranking should be conditional on `timestamp`

Comment: so each retweet is a tweet, and within each of these groups you want to order the users according to the timestamp??

Comment: No, but I want to assign higher values to user who retweeted first. The if ranking goes incremental the order should be `-timestamp`

Comment: User 2 if first at tweeting and get an higher rank (because I want to measure influence...)

Comment: It still assigns the same value to each retweet

Comment: It will give OP the error they mentioned above. Because they already assigned `ranking`. They also wanted the aggregated result. You can roll back if you don't like it. I don't care really. Only was trying to help.

Comment: it's fine, thanks alot! learned a lot from you ! I didnt read the aggregate part in the OP, my bad, sorry